# Counting files Mac vs Windows Python

Tags: python, windows, macos, glob

I have a code that is intended to count files from a directory and read lines from a .txt file.

The code works fine on my Mac but will not work on Windows (even when I change the path). This is the code on Windows:

```
import glob
path = 'E:\calpy_em27_neu\spectra_out_demo\140803\*'
files = glob.glob(path)

with open('info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:
    for count, line in enumerate(infofile):
        print count
print(len(files))
```

On windows I get the output:

```
0
1
1
3
0
```

On Mac I get the (correct) output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

because there are four lines in the infofile and four files in the directory called. Any idea why this isn't working properly on Windows?

Comment: Is the `1` on the third line of the Windows output actually what you get, or is that a typo? Because the code you've shown can't possibly emit that `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to escape the backslash character. Try one of these:

```
path = r'E:\calpy_em27_neu\spectra_out_demo\140803\*'
path = 'E:\\calpy_em27_neu\\spectra_out_demo\\140803\\*'
path = 'E:/calpy_em27_neu/spectra_out_demo/140803/*'
```

Comment: yes, the first one worked immediately! do you know the reasoning for this?

Comment: @alli: "because it is [defined](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) in the language". If you have an inquisitive mind, try the other two as well.